# Method returns undefined on client

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I am able to generate a random nonce on the server and it shows up on console, but that value is not getting returned to the client.

Server method:

```
Meteor.methods({
    'user.generateNewLoginAttempt': function(user_address) {
        let exists = Meteor.users.findOne({
            username: user_address
        });
        let nonce = Random.secret(16);

        console.log(nonce); //shows random string

        if (exists) {
            // user already exists, update nonce
            Meteor.users.update(exists._id, {
                $set: {
                    nonce: nonce
                }
            });
        } else {
            // create new user
            let userId = Accounts.createUser({
                username: user_address,
                address: user_address,
                nonce: nonce
            });
        }

        return nonce;
    },
});
```

Client code:

```
Meteor.call('user.generateNewLoginAttempt', user_address, function(err, nonce) {
    if (err)
        console.log(err);
    /shows up internal server error
    // nonce = the nonce generated on server
    else {
        console.log('nonce: ' + nonce);
        // hash nonce
        let sh3_nonce = web3.sha3(nonce); // depending on web3 version use: web3.utils.sha3(nonce)
        console.log('sh3 hashed nonce: ' + sh3_nonce);

        // sign hashed nonce
        web3.eth.sign(user_address, sh3_nonce, function(err, res) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                // res = the signed nonce
                // login with signed nonce
                login(res);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

On the client side, it shows `Internal Server Error(500)`. I tried removing most of the code from the server method and just returning some value, but that also doesn't work.

Comment: Looks like the issue is in `Accounts.createUser` call. Put a `try-catch` around it and see what error you are getting. Could be user already exists or password issues, etx. Hope it helps. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can set the nonce and the address on the user document like that, as I recall Accounts.createUser consumes only username, password, email and profile, so if you want to save the nonce and the address on the user object you need to insert them into the "profile" object.

**KEEP IN MIND! using the profile to keep user data is not encouraged** since the default meteor behaviour is to **allow users to edit the profile**, so if you do that you'll need to make sure you set the allow/deny policies yourself.

in my opinion you'll be much better off keeping user details in a separate collection.